# How to use SQL's BETWEEN condition when you're excluding a number in between?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Right now, I'm using the BETWEEN condition to gather up account numbers, but the only account numbers I want to grab are:

2999, 3000 to 3004, and 3006 - 3010 (basically skipping 3005)

How would I format the BETWEEN?

Comment: How about either `X BETWEEN 2999 AND 3004 OR X BETWEEN 3006 AND 3010` or `X BETWEEN 2999 AND 3010 AND X <> 3005` ?

Comment: I will just leave this here for you to view. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Thank you Lasse, I used your first method.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `NOT IN` to exclude values from range:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE col BETWEEN 2999 AND 3010
  AND col NOT IN (3005) -- values you want to exclude
```